# Convert from data object to business object. Best practice

Tags: c#, data-access-layer

Let's say that there is a UserEntity in the DataLayer that needs to be converted to a User in the BusinessLayer. There is not a 1:1 mapping between these two types and inheritance is not an option.

I want to convert User to UserEntity and the other way around. What is the best way of doing this? I see a few patterns but I don't know which is better and why:

1. Implement in User 2 methods: From Entity and ToEntity
2. Implement TypeConverter
3. Overload the = operator

Answer (score 2):

Do not overload assignment operator - it's nasty and will bite any developer that will inherit your code. It's better to be explicit.

I would encapsulate the logic for mapping those two types (or more, if it's not 1:1) in a separate class. Create an `UserAdapter` class where you can implement your `ToEntity` / `FromEntity` methods.

And make sure you use **[AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)** to minimize the amount of code.

> AutoMapper uses a fluent configuration
>   API to define an object-object mapping
>   strategy. AutoMapper uses a
>   convention-based matching algorithm to
>   match up source to destination values.
>   Currently, AutoMapper is geared
>   towards model projection scenarios to
>   flatten complex object models to DTOs
>   and other simple objects, whose design
>   is better suited for serialization,
>   communication, messaging, or simply an
>   anti-corruption layer between the
>   domain and application layer.

**Update:**

You can add those methods to `User` class, and it may be enough for a small project. I'm a bit purist when it comes to the design and would keep adapter logic outside of those classes. *Why should the `User` class be dependant and have any knowledge of `UserEntity` class?* It's a bit of a smell for me to tie them together. A separate layer of adapters is more future-proof. For example, should you have to replace your database layer with a different one (ie. moving from Linq2SQL to EntityFramework or Dapper) all you need to do is to create new adapters - your business classes will remain intact.

Comment: Why not add ToEntity/FromEntity in the User class?